# How to disable components completely in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this razor code and I intend to disable the entire component (not responding to user inputs and visibly distinctive) based on a variable that changes on some event:

```
<div @bind-Enabled=@NoItemSelected >      
   <Component01 Param1="@DataItem01" />
</div>

@code{

  public DataItem DataItem01 {get; set;}
  public bool NoItemSelected => DataItem01 != null;
}
```

Obviously trying to set the div's enabled state is not working.

The component contains many elements so I can't disable them one-by-one based on an input parameter.

Any idea how I should set the disabled state to the entire component?

Answer (score 0):

You can place if statements around your components

```
@if (NoItemSelected == false)
{   
    <Component01 Param1="@DataItem01" />
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it hide the component?

Comment: @AdnanSharif  Do you mean you think it should be if (NoItemSelected). I was just reading the previous answer that stated "Now, when the variable NoItemSelected is true, the div element is disabled, and when it is false it is enabled"

Comment: No I didn't mean that. As you wrapped wrapped the component inside a `if block`, the component should not be visible in UI. But the requirement is the component should be visible but should not respond to users' action (which means the component is disabled).

Comment: @AdnanSharif. Looks like I misunderstood the users intention if they still want the UI to be visible.